# filling particular grid view column from dataset

Tags: vb.net

I have a datagridview ,,i want to fill this datagrid view  particular column from my dataset..
i am filling my dataset like this:

```
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("DashBordFetch", con.connect) cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure cmd.Parameters.Add("@locid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = locid
da.SelectCommand = cmd
da.Fill(ds)
```

After filling dataset i want to fill my datagrid view first column .so i try to give code like this:
but this showing error *property item read only*

```
DgvUnclosed.Columns(0) = ds.Tables(0).Columns(0)  ![enter image description here][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the DataSource property on your grid - set it to the table.

Research "data binding" for the datagridview...